# How To Generate Mono<Map<Map<List>> from Flux

Tags: java, project-reactor, reactive

I have a flux of response form below responses as `Flux.<Response>fromIterable(responses)`. I want to convert this to Mono of map as follows:

> Mono< Map< String, Map< String, Collection< Response>>>> collectMap = ?

where company is first key for which another map of response will be generated with category as key.

```
List< Response> responses = new ArrayList(){
            {
                add(Response.builder().company("Samsung").category("Tab").price("$2000").itemName("Note").build());
                add(Response.builder().company("Samsung").category("Phone").price("$2000").itemName("S9").build());
                add(Response.builder().company("Samsung").category("Phone").price("$1000").itemName("S8").build());
                add(Response.builder().company("Iphone").category("Phone").price("$5000").itemName("Iphone8").build());
                add(Response.builder().company("Iphone").category("Tab").price("$5000").itemName("Tab").build());
            }
        };
```

Though I am able to achieve initial map as follow

```
Mono<Map<String, Collection<Response>>> collect = Flux.<Response>fromIterable( responses )
                .collectMultimap( Response::getCompany );
```

Do someone has an idea how I can achieve my goal here.

Comment: @MuratOzkan, your reply is intresting. on a select *, User as tableName from User, I get the data:

Flux<Map<String,Object>> data
For many tables, I need to create return a Json where I specify the table name and its data. so i return :

Mono<Map<String,Collection<String,Object>>> alltablesDatas
Do you have an idea how to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `collectMultiMap` or `collectMap` helps you directly in this case:

1. The `collectMultiMap` (and its overloads) only can return `Map<T, Collection<V>` which is clearly different than what you want. Of course, you can process the resulting value set (namely the `Collection<V>` part of the map) with a O(n) complexity.
2. On the other hand `collectMap` (and its overloads) look a bit more promising, if you provide the value function. However, you don't have access to other `V` objects, which forbids you to build the `Collection<V>`.

The solution I came up with is using `reduce`; though the return type is:
`Mono<Map<String, Map<String, List<Response>>>>` (mind the `List<V>` instead of `Collection<V>`)

```
return Flux.<Response>fromIterable( responses )
           .reduce(new HashMap<>(), (map, user) -> {
                map.getOrDefault(user.getId(), new HashMap<>())
                        .getOrDefault(user.getEmail(), new ArrayList<>())
                        .add(user);
                return map;
            });
```

The full type for the `HashMap` in `reduce` is `HashMap<String, Map<String, List<AppUser>>>`, thankfully Java can deduce that from the return type of the method or the type of the assigned variable.

Comment: Where do you add new entries to the map in this code? It's look like the map return has size 0